# unable to save file name on database

Tags: asp.net

I am try to save file_name and path of the file on database. but unable to save it :(. database Connection working fine,but i dn't know what is problem

```
 con.Open();
         string fileExt = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.FileName);
         SqlCommand cmd = new  SqlCommand("insertintoTbl_Videos(VideoName,VideoPath)values(@VideoName,@VideoPath)",con);
        if (fileExt == ".avi")
        {
            try
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VideoName",  "video/"+FileUpload1.FileName);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VideoPath", "video/" +FileUpload1.FileName);
                FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/video/" + FileUpload1.FileName)); 
                Literal1.Text = "upload"; 
   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Label1.Text = "ERROR: " + ex.Message.ToString();
            }

        }
        else
        {
            Label1.Text = "Only .avi files allowed!";
        }

    }
        }
```

Comment: One thing .I how to know how is it possible when user upload video .automatically player play the file .after that he can save file on server

Comment: I see you're not doing anything to ensure filenames are unique on your data store. That's probably something you need to do.

Comment: MattW Plz explain more

Comment: thnx MattW for help.Problem is solve.is it possible when user upload video .automatically player play the file .after that he/she can save file on server

Comment: If user A uploads video.avi, and user B later also uploads a different file also called video.avi, you're probably going to overwrite user A's file, unless it just fails. Given you've got a database handy in which you can store both a client-visible and an internal file name, you can rename your files for storage to, say, `Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".avi"` and avoid those types of clash, but when you serve the content back to users you can translate the filename back to the original if needed.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't provided the command with a SqlConnection. You need to:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new  SqlCommand("insertintoTbl_Videos(VideoName,VideoPath)values(@VideoName,@VideoPath)", con);
```

You also don't actually execute the command anywhere. That also needs to be done explicitly:

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```